# Merge multiple variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset such that the same variable is contained in difference columns for each subject. I want to merge them to the same columns.

E.g.:, I have this dataframe, and there are three DVs, but they are in different columns (A,B,C) for different subjects.

```
data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), DV1_A=c(1,NA,NA), DV1_B= c(NA,4,NA), DV1_C = c(NA,NA,5), DV2_A=c(3,NA,NA), DV2_B=c(NA,3,NA), DV2_C=c(NA,NA,5), FACT = c("A","B","C"))
```

How can I merge them to just two columns? so the result is:

```
data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), DV1_A=c(1,NA,NA), DV1_B= c(NA,4,NA), DV1_C = c(NA,NA,5), DV2_A=c(3,NA,NA), DV2_B=c(NA,3,NA), DV2_C=c(NA,NA,5), FACT = c("A","B","C"), DV_1 = c(1,4,5), DV_2 = c(3,3,5))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `coalesce` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DV_1 = coalesce(DV1_A, DV1_B, DV1_C),
         DV_2 = coalesce(DV2_A, DV2_B, DV2_C))
```

If you have a lot of `DV` *columns* to combine, you might not want to type all the column names. In this case, you can first `grep` the column names for each `DV`, parse each name to symbols with `rlang::syms`, then splice (`!!!`) the symbols in `coalesce` (Advice from @hadley):

```
library(rlang)
var_quo1 = syms(grep("DV1", names(df), value = TRUE))
var_quo2 = syms(grep("DV2", names(df), value = TRUE))

df %>%
  mutate(DV_1 = coalesce(!!! var_quo1),
         DV_2 = coalesce(!!! var_quo2))
```

If instead, you have a ton of *`DV`'s*, you might not even want to type all the `coalesce` lines, in this case, you can create a function that outputs one `DV` column given an input number and `lapply` + `bind_col` all of them together:

```
DV_combine = function(num_DVs){

  DV_name = sym(paste0("DV", num_DVs))
  DV_syms = syms(grep(paste0("DV", num_DVs), names(df), value = TRUE))

  df %>%
    transmute(!!DV_name := coalesce(!!! DV_syms))
}

bind_cols(df, lapply(1:2, DV_combine))
```

**Result:**

```
  ID DV1_A DV1_B DV1_C DV2_A DV2_B DV2_C FACT DV_1 DV_2
1  1     1    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    A    1    3
2  2    NA     4    NA    NA     3    NA    B    4    3
3  3    NA    NA     5    NA    NA     5    C    5    5
```

**Note:**

This method will work for both `numeric` and `character` class columns, but not `factor`'s. One should first convert the `factor` columns to character before using this method.

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3), DV1_A = c(1, NA, NA), DV1_B = c(NA, 
4, NA), DV1_C = c(NA, NA, 5), DV2_A = c(3, NA, NA), DV2_B = c(NA, 
3, NA), DV2_C = c(NA, NA, 5), FACT = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "DV1_A", "DV1_B", 
"DV1_C", "DV2_A", "DV2_B", "DV2_C", "FACT"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Generally I'd advise against splicing data frames into calls with `!!!`. It's better to splice in variable names

Comment: Thanks for the advice @hadley, but do you mean something like `grep`ing the colnames, parsing to quosures, then splicing with `!!!`? I was trying to take advantage of `starts_with`, but yea, I agree that splicing whole dataframes is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The main challenge is that the `select()` syntax is so nice that you want to use it in vectorised functions that take `...`, but there's no great way to do so currently.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this via `gather` and `spread` with `tidyr` and `dplyr`.  Less concise than @useR's solution, but might be useful if you need to do any intermediate manipulation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -ID, -FACT, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(variable = gsub("\\_[A-Z]", "", variable)) %>% 
  spread(variable, value) %>% 
  left_join(df)

  ID FACT DV1 DV2 DV1_A DV1_B DV1_C DV2_A DV2_B DV2_C
1  1    A   1   3     1    NA    NA     3    NA    NA
2  2    B   4   3    NA     4    NA    NA     3    NA
3  3    C   5   5    NA    NA     5    NA    NA     5
```

Answer (score 1):

The base `transform` will do this:

```
d <- transform(d, 
               DV1 = rowSums(d[c("DV1_A", "DV1_B", "DV1_C")], na.rm=T),
               DV2 = rowSums(d[c("DV2_A", "DV2_B", "DV2_C")], na.rm=T)
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, though not a very elegant solution when you could use the coalesce function already mentioned:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(DV1 = ifelse(!is.na(DV1_A),paste(DV1_A),ifelse(!is.na(DV1_B),paste(DV1_B),ifelse(!is.na(DV1_C),paste(DV1_C),""))), DV2 = ifelse(!is.na(DV2_A),paste(DV2_A),ifelse(!is.na(DV2_B),paste(DV2_B),ifelse(!is.na(DV2_C),paste(DV2_C),""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution similar to @userR, but rather than creating each column individually, this creates a list of expressions that get evaluated all at once. It may still suffer the same "don't splice data frames into calls with `!!!`" fault that was mentioned in the comments since it uses `select(.)`, but I thought I would post anyways.

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), DV1_A=c(1,NA,NA), 
                 DV1_B= c(NA,4,NA), DV1_C = c(NA,NA,5), 
                 DV2_A=c(3,NA,NA), DV2_B=c(NA,3,NA), 
                 DV2_C=c(NA,NA,5), FACT = c("A","B","C"))

create_DV <- function(num) {
  DV_name <- sym(paste0("DV_", num))
  DV_char <- paste0("DV", num)

  expr(!! DV_name := select(., contains(!! DV_char)) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))
}

DV_expr_list <- c(1,2) %>% 
  lapply(create_DV)

df %>%
  mutate(
    !!! DV_expr_list
  )
#>   ID DV1_A DV1_B DV1_C DV2_A DV2_B DV2_C FACT DV_1 DV_2
#> 1  1     1    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    A    1    3
#> 2  2    NA     4    NA    NA     3    NA    B    4    3
#> 3  3    NA    NA     5    NA    NA     5    C    5    5
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table`  solution using `melt()` to reshape *two measure variables simultaneously:*

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("DV1", "DV2")
melt(setDT(DF), measure.vars = patterns(cols), value.name = cols, na.rm = TRUE)[
  , -"variable"]
```

> ```
>    ID FACT DV1 DV2
> 1:  1    A   1   3
> 2:  2    B   4   3
> 3:  3    C   5   5
> ```

Now, the six columns have been merged to just two columns as requested by the OP.

However, the OP has given a data.frame with the expected result where the new columns are appended to the existing  columns. This can be achieved by joining above result with the original data frame:

```
 setDT(DF)[melt(DF, measure.vars = patterns(cols), value.name = cols, na.rm = TRUE)[
  , -"variable"], on = .(ID, FACT)]
```

> ```
>    ID DV1_A DV1_B DV1_C DV2_A DV2_B DV2_C FACT DV1 DV2
> 1:  1     1    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    A   1   3
> 2:  2    NA     4    NA    NA     3    NA    B   4   3
> 3:  3    NA    NA     5    NA    NA     5    C   5   5
> ```