# How to check if NA within replace() function in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

In my dataset, the duration of a activity is either given in hours (column `duration_hours`) or in minutes (column `duration_minutes`). If it is given in hours, the `duration_minutes` column is empty (`NA`) and vice versa.
I now want to convert the values given in minutes into hours by dividing them by 60 (minutes).

To do so I tried this command:

`df <- df %>% mutate(duration_recoded = replace(duration_minutes, !is.na(duration_minutes), duration_minutes / 60))`

However, the command produces incorrect results and this warning message is shown:

```
Warning message:
In x[list] <- values :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Can anybody tell me where my mistake is?

Here's some sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(duration_hours = c(1, NA, 2, NA, 1), duration_minutes = c(NA, 25, NA, 30, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271093/merge-multiple-variables-in-r, but not totally sure without sample data

Comment: I added sample data to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the `coalesce()` function from the `dplyr` package here:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(duration_recoded = coalesce(duration_hours, duration_minutes / 60))
```

This should work because if the `duration_hours` be non `NA`, then `coalesce` would simply grab it and assign it to `duration_recorded`.  If `duration_hours` is actually `NA`, then it would pass and instead take `duration_minutes` divided by 60.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thanks a lot!
However, it would really help me to also understand what was the issue with my approach. I feel it's no different to what was suggested e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28013895/12912548

Comment: @mpds The problem with your current approach is that you only want to replace with the duration minutes divided by 60 if the duration hours field be empty.

Comment: But isn't this basically the same as in the example, where the the value is changed when the value is 4? Asked differently, is the issue with the `!is.na(duration_minutes)` or with the `duration_minutes / 60` part of the command?

Comment: No, your usage/understanding of `replace()` is incorrect, and the logic must be wrong, because you need to check for the presence of the `duration_hours` before deciding what is the replacement.

Comment: Isn't this what my code does (at least what I'm trying to make it do) ? 
First it checks if `duration_hours`is not empty and only then it replaces it with its own value divided by 60.

Comment: `replace(duration_minutes, !is.na(duration_minutes), duration_minutes / 60)` ... I don't see `duration_hours` mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Oh right, that was a mistake in my previous comment. The command does indeed not include `duration_hours`. However, there is no need for it because only either `duration_hours` (if duration is more than 60 minutes) or `duration_minutes`(if less than 60 minutes) has a value. The other one will always be `NA`. With my command I only want to recode the value of `duration_minutes`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that duration minutes is a vector and when you divide by 60 you are performing a vector operation. Let's use an example df:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 1
  duration_minutes
             <dbl>
1               10
2               20
3               30
4               NA
5               50
6               NA
7               60
```

In this case, `df$duraction_minutes / 60` results in:

```
0.1666667 0.3333333 0.5000000        NA 0.8333333        NA 1.0000000
```

That means that you are trying to replace every NA value with a vector of multiple values... That is why your warning message says `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.

You either have to use some function that aggregates multiple values to a single value (such as `sum()`, `mean()`, `first()`, etc) or you have to select a single value to act as a replacement. the `coalesce()` function is just finding the first non-missing element.

Comment: If my code produced the values given in your post, everything would be fine. However, if you try my sample data, there are two rows that have values for `duration_minutes` and should therefore be recoded. The first non-NA element (25) is ignored by the code and the second one (30) is recoded incorrectly (value of 0.416 instead of 0.5).