# How to merge multiple columns with partial column name and patterns

Tags: r

I have data collected in a manner that goes from 2010 to 2022, about several sub topics and nuances.
I want to merge the columns based on different years. The problem is the year number lies in between the variable name, for example: Za**2010**a01, and the text and numbers before and after the year number are in a pattern themselves, so not constant throughout the variable names, except the first "Z". Apologies if I can't explain it properly ( new to R, using it for data analysis purposes). Here is an example of how column names look like.

`colnames(tab) <- c('Za2010a01','Za2010a02','Za2010a03','Za2010b01','Za2010b02','Za2010b03','Za2010c01','Za2010c02','Za2010c03','Zb2010a01','Zb2010a02','Zb2010a03','Za2011a01','Za2011a02','Za2011a03')` and so on...
I want all the variables for different years to be merged together, so Za2010a01 and Za2011a01 become Zaa01, Za2010a02 and Za2011a02 become Zaa02. I am sure there won't be any overlapping since in my dataset there are a lot of "NA" meant to be filled by merging.
The problem is everything in the variable names is in a pattern/keeps changing. Except for the initial "Z", the "a" before and after the year name changes and the digits at the end also change throughout.
I have more than 5000 variables so can not individually add every column.

Reference to one of the similar questions asked before:
[Merge multiple variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271093/merge-multiple-variables-in-r)

I looked around the previous questions and figured out that I might have to use `coalesce` from `dplyr` but can't seem to figure out the exact expression for the problem I am trying to solve.
Thus, help would be appreciated. Feel free to ask more.

Comment: Hi  statmach, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. You only need enough rows and columns to replicate the issue you are facing. Thanks

Comment: If you want to remove the year from the middle of the column names, and the year pattern is the same for every column name e.g.the year value that you want to remove is the only occurrence of four consecutive numbers in any column name, then `colnames(tab) <- gsub("\\d{4}", "", colnames(tab))` will work. Then you should be able to `coalesce()` your columns, but without a sample of your data, it is hard to be 100% certain.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to convert to long format, remove the year numbers from the column names, and then convert back into wide, adding rows for the duplicate names.

Here is some dummy data:

```
> matrix <- matrix(data=sample(1:100, 48) ,nrow=4, ncol=4)
> DF <- as.data.frame(matrix)
> names(DF) <- paste0("Za",paste0(rep(c(2001,2002), each = 2),
+                                 c("a01","b02")))
> DF
  Za2001a01 Za2001b02 Za2002a01 Za2002b02
1        80        12        35        31
2        69        94        88        64
3        93        14         1        53
4        59        43        51        41
```

Now for the pivoting to long, changing the column names, and pivoting back to wide:

```
> library(tidyr)
> DFLong <- pivot_longer(DF,cols=everything(),names_to="OldNames")
> 
> #Create the new column names
> DFLong$NewNames <- sub("[0-9]{4}","",DFLong$OldNames)
> 
> #Pivot the values and new column names wider, and unnest the result to keep it as a data frame
> DFMerged <- pivot_wider(DFLong[,c("value","NewNames")],
+                         names_from = NewNames,
+                         values_from = value,
+                         values_fn = list) %>% 
+     unnest(cols=everything())
> 
> DFMerged
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  Zaa01 Zab02
  <int> <int>
1    26    38
2     8    83
3    57    40
4    64    25
5    62    39
6    55    70
7    51     9
8    49    36
```